# SQL, извлечь строки с наибольшими совпадениями по столбцу

Tags: sql, выборка

Есть таблица **enter** с полями **id, uid, date**.

Нужно извлечь 5 **uid**, которые встречаются чаще всего, от самого часто встречающегося, и, соответственно, еще 4, уступающих первому.

Как это можно реализовать? Сам ни до каких идей дойти не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вернет 5 самых встречающихся `uid` и кол-во раз, которое они встретились в таблице `count`

```
    select count(uid) as count, uid
    from enter 
    group by uid 
    order by count desc
    limit 5
```

Comment: Мне кажется - нужно исправить! Вместо `id` в `select` - нужно `uid`.

Comment: @Majestio, Спасибо. Поправил

Answer (score 2):

Например так (пробовал для для MySQL):

```
SELECT
  u.uid, 
  COUNT(u.uid)
FROM
  enter AS u
GROUP BY
  u.uid
ORDER BY
  COUNT(u.uid) DESC
LIMIT
  5
```